# Using NReco video convertor, Format.flv reference cant be solve

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, video

I'm using NReco to convert a few images into a video
however i faced a problem with this code

```
(new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter()).ConvertMedia(pathToVideoFile, pathToOutputMp4File, Formats.mp4)
```

the Formats.mp4 was in error (reference not found)
i've been searching the reference but are not able to solve this.

Need help ! thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is an error in their example online.  The easiest thing to do is add a using statement to your code so you can make your code more readable and spend less time typing:

```
using NReco.VideoConverter;
```

Then you can access what you want like this:

```
FFMpegConverter ff = new FFMpegConverter();
ff.ConvertMedia(pathToVideoFile, pathToOutputMp4File, Format.mp4);
```

Note that there is no 's' on the end of `Format`.  Also, I would be careful about using an inline construct (temporary object) the way you have done in your code sniplet.  I don't know how they are managing resources inside their class and what their threading model looks like.  It would be a lot safer to create your converter object like I have above and use it that way.

Comment: You're right this was just typo in the code snippet (fixed). Note that Format.mp4 is just a string constant "mp4" and it is possible to use any format string specifier supported by FFMpeg tool.